# Code not plotting - Function should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope"

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am getting this as an orange error - not sure what I have done wrong or whether this error is the reason that the code doesn't plot. I am brand new to Pine-script and any assistance would be invaluable. Many thanks in advance Alastair

```
//@version=5
indicator("PCY TEST4")

//Get User Inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

//Variables 
a = 0.33
PCY = 0.0
PCYi = 0.0

// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma

minMacd=0.0
for i = 0 to (signal_length[1])
    minMacd := ta.min(macd)
    
maxMacd=0.0
for i = 0 to (signal_length[1])
    maxMacd := ta.max(macd)

//maxMacd = ta.min(macd)
//minMacd = ta.max(macd)
//signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
//hist = macd - signal
delta = maxMacd-(fast_ma - slow_ma)/(maxMacd -minMacd)

for i = 0 to (signal_length)
    PCYi := a*((delta - PCYi[1])+PCYi[1])
    PCYi

//Plotting
plot(PCYi)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're calculating the min/max in a for loop
Those functions should (not mandatory but strongly recommended) be calculated at every candle instead

```
for i = 0 to (signal_length[1])
    minMacd := ta.min(macd)
    
maxMacd=0.0
for i = 0 to (signal_length[1])
    maxMacd := ta.max(macd)
```

If you want to calculate the min/max over a X period of time, maybe use the ta.highest/ta.lowest functions instead :)
And of course, those 2 should be called at every candle (i.e. not in a if, for,... statement)

Comment: Hi Dave - I would like to thank you for taking the time to answer this question its Much Appreciated!!! As I am completely new to pine script might I ask how you call this at each candle or what the code might look like? Kindest regards Alastair

Comment: remove the for i = 0 line ....
keep the minMacd = ta.lowest(macd, signal_length[1])

Comment: Hi David, Once again thank you kindly for taking the time to assist me - I have done what you recommended but unfortunately I am receiving a study error ( invalid value for length argument 0.0 in lowest function it must be >0 ) when I add to chart - any thoughts??

Comment: try minMacd = ta.lowest(macd, signal_length)
Make sure the second parameter of the ta.lowest function is always greater than 0